# types.GenericAlias - subscriptable Types and their use

Tags: python, namedtuple

I was working with namedtuples and learned something that I found odd at first. Still not quite sure how or why this works and what can be the use of this:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Card = namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit'])
```

Above code works fine and creates a new Class - Card, which is a subclass of tuple class.

Now when I do this:

```
newCard = Card('7', 'Hearts')
```

It serves my purpose of creating a new card. But when I do this:

```
newCard = Card['7', 'Hearts']
```

It does not work as expected but also does not throw any error. Normally, *Types* are not subscriptable and if I try the same with any other class:

```
class FrenchDeck:
      Pass

newDeck = FrenchDeck[1]
```

It throws following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sbvik\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Chapter1.py", line 27, in <module>
    c = FrenchDeck[1]
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

But if I inherit my FrenchDeck class like this:

```
class FrenchDeck(tuple):
      Pass

newDeck = FrenchDeck[1]
```

No error is thrown.

Then I checked the type of `newDeck` it turns out to be `<class 'types.GenericAlias'>`

I am not sure what 'types.GenericAlias' means, what's its purpose and how is it used?
Also, why was `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable` not thrown in this case?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am new to this concept and it seems to be some advance level stuff. Could you please explain this to me?